# can't push ember cli app to heroku due to broccoli-sass and node-sass

Tags: node.js, heroku, ember.js, ember-cli

I've been trying to deploy to `Heroku` and it keeps throwing me an error. Apparently `node 0.12` was not compatible with `node-sass` so I updated to `node-sass 2.0.1` but it still doesn't work. I'm using `ember cli 0.1.15`

```
Module did not self-register.
       Error: Module did not self-register.
           at Error (native)
           at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
           at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
           at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
           at require (module.js:384:17)
           at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_9fa8a1b16bb172aacd5dffe37fe967c1/node_modules/broccoli-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:181:15)
           at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
           at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
           at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ember CLI app
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is happening because Heroku is using the last version of `nodejs` `0.12.0` which is incompatible with `node-sass` < `2.0.1` which is being use by `broccoli-sass`, you updated your local version of `node-sass` but `broccoli-sass` is still using the old version of `node-sass`
There are some pull requests on `broccoli-sass` to fix that issue

https://github.com/joliss/broccoli-sass/pull/49
https://github.com/joliss/broccoli-sass/pull/43

Meanwhile you can modify your `package.json`

from

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  }
```

to

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x"
  }
```